# How to limit the number of entries/records to a maximum in a List

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin

how to limit record of a list programmatically or configuration.

When the user insert record in the list if this list has exceeded the maximum numbers of record allowed, the form of insert have to show a message with a text as:

"Numbers of records has exceeded the permitted limit"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On 2013 CSR and the [OnPreRender function](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views) is one, and maybe even the best way of skinning this cat.
You will have to read the whole list and then not display the Form but a message.

But you can do without CSR and make SharePoint do half the work for you.

A quick and easy ductape patch from the olden days is to hide the NewForm contents.

- On the NewForm.aspx page add a ListView WebPart, make it list **all** your items
  change the WebPart Layouts Properties Zone-Index to 1 to make it display **below** the NewForm
- Add another WebPart, use a Content Editor WebPart with the contents:

  **<SCRIPT>**

  ```
  SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', null, function(){//execute after pageload
      var items = document.getElementsByClassName('ms-itmhover');//all displayed listitems
      if (items.length > 10) {//maximum number of items
          var form = document.getElementsByClassName('ms-formtable')[0];//new form
          while (form.tagName !== 'DIV') {//go up to the enclosing DIV
              form = form.parentNode;
          }
          form.innerHTML = '<h1>Numbers of records has exceeded the permitted limit: '+items.length+'</h1>';
      } else {//optional: hide the View with all the items
          var itemlist=items[0];//first item
          while (itemlist.tagName !== 'DIV') {//go up to enclosing DIV
              itemlist = itemlist.parentNode;
          }
          itemlist.style.display='none';
      }
  });
  ```

  **</SCRIPT>**

Tip: place the javascript in a separate file and link the Content Editor Web Part to it.. makes it easier to edit... you still have to include the < script> tag!!

[image]

## Another alternative is:

## [Limit only one entry per day per user in sharepoint list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/153059/limit-only-one-entry-per-day-per-user-in-sharepoint-list/156829#156829)

iJS

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I executed the above JSOM code but it is hiding entire listview web part. I but i need to hide only "New Item" from DisplayForm.aspx page.
How could i fix this this issue on above solution.

Comment: [I am no longer in the SP world, yeah!] You have to change the JavaScript (this is not JSOM) to match your requirements.... learn JavaScript DOM operations

Answer (score 1):

You can crate Before Event Handler to achive this. You can add business logic for checking the number of allowed records in the method `itemAdding`

Comment: A before ER in SharePoint *Online*?

Comment: Could you show me some code?

Comment: I'm quite sure before ER are not possible in Online environment...

Comment: suppose that is on-premise

Comment: It is even possible with SharePoint Online as well. Remote Event Receiver can be used to achieve this. In Remote event receiver you have to write your business logic in 'ProcessEvent():' in this method. [Link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepointdevelopersupport/archive/2013/03/13/how-to-create-a-remote-event-receiver-for-a-sharepoint-hosted-app.aspx)

Comment: You can get many code samples for on-premise SharePoint Before Event receiver. If you need any more help please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with JavaScript as well. You can add business logic and return false if number of records is exceeded in your `Presave`action.

Comment: Hello Akhoy. I am trying to implement this. For example i have a column A and Column B. Only if Column A is greater than or equal to Column B, i want to save the item or else display a test message. Can you please brief me the code? I am not so strong in JavaScript? I don't want to do this through validation setting. I want to do this through JavaScript on Newform.aspx. Plesae help.

Comment: You need to use PreSaveAction. Check this: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31330.sharepoint-using-presaveaction-function-on-custom-list-forms.aspx