# Link to Edit button on page for item & conditionally format

Tags: sharepoint-online, formatting, conditional

In SharePoint Online (E3 subscription) I have 5 lists in a site and in each list the user is to enter 1 item. The end result is to enable the Create and Edit button conditionally on a page next to text of list name. The only field that could have a unique value in the lists would be Created By. I have the link for Create. I need the link for each list's Edit button as well as how to enable/disable the other links on the page.

- List 1 Create link enabled, all other links disabled
- User clicks List 1 Create link, enters data and saves
- List 1 Edit button enabled, all other links disabled
- List 1 Field 'Approved' default = False. When supervisor approves data through workflow or field on a page, 'Approved' is ticked becoming True.
- List 2 Create link enabled, all other links disabled
- Do for all lists

[image: Format Changes]

I have the link to the Edit for each list and the end of the link has 'ID=1'. I don't want to hard code 'ID=1' just in case the item has to be deleted for some reason since it auto number increments.

I have read about creating a workflow that puts a copy of the Created By into a field and check to make sure that field is unique. That works for making sure there is a unique entry. I also need the link for the Edit button as well as the conditional formatting enable/disable.

I could use [SP.List.getItems](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms457534.aspx) and in the WHERE put in 'Approved'=True

How would I get the ID or would I use Created By = Me

Where would I use the JS and how would I conditionally format text or images on the page?

With all the conditional formatting, do I need to check for a unique record per user?

Is there a different way to think about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How would I get the ID or would I use Created By = Me**
You will be using Created By = Me and then fetch the corresponding item to it. If the item count is returned 0, create the item

**Where would I use the JS and how would I conditionally format text or images on the page?**
Just create an HTML file and add javascript and content to it. Then add a content editor webpart on the page and link it to the HTML file

**With all the conditional formatting, do I need to check for a unique record per user?**
Once you implement the Created BY = Me, you won't need to. It will already be checking.

1. Get items for the current user
2. Check if itemCount= 0
3. If rowCount = 0, add the item to the list
4. else, edit the item

Comment: I see what you mean. Here is a tutorial I found to get me started: [link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20764.sharepoint-2013-build-a-webpart-using-html-javascript-and-the-xml-viewer-web-part.aspx) Thanks!

Comment: Here is another technique that might help: [http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/153059/limit-only-one-entry-per-day-per-user-in-sharepoint-list](limit-only-one-entry-per-day-per-user-in-sharepoint-list)