# Limiting the number of items in a list

Tags: list, validation, size

I'm trying to limit the number through the use of validation settings. I was hoping of creating the max number of forms, then forcing it so no forms can be created. But I still would want the forms to be able to be edited.

I'm willing to take other paths if this one does not work.

Comment: Have you searched? Guess not: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/153059/limit-only-one-entry-per-day-per-user-in-sharepoint-list/156829#156829

Comment: One of the approaches could be the use of validation with ID column. It auto increments by 1, so you could set a condition like ID<1000. However that would still leave a problem when items are deleted from your list.

Comment: ..Can't you just create the forms and then lock down the permissions/ hide all of the links to create a new form? That way users can edit/delete the current forms but can't create new ones