# Duplicating a View/Table

Tags: duplicate

I have a table on a page (view/table) which is a checklist. I have formatted it and it looks great as a beta at present. I want to be able to duplicate this up to 100 times for different people to use and tick off. No interaction is required between them. I was kinda thinking a template that could just be activated on each page created for that person?

Comment: does it save any data back to the SharePoint list? If not, why not just make a simple html page and have it in a webpart for each page?

Comment: I agree with @Mike , Even if you want to save to SP List, you can define a specific list, where you can have the actual data which needs to be duplicated, and other lists to say store the input from each user

Comment: and of course do all this stuff in Webpart

Answer (score 0):

- Create a custom SharePoint List
- Use SharePoint Designer to edit the newform.aspx to the layout you want

If you want to limit the entries per person adapt: [Limit only one entry per day per user in sharepoint list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/153059/limit-only-one-entry-per-day-per-user-in-sharepoint-list)