# make List item non Editable dynamically

Tags: list, list-view, list-form, updatelistitems, insert-update-listitem

Is it Possible to make list item non editable based on one of its column value.
for example i have list fees which has a column submitted.when submitted is false user can edit that item but not when it is set to true.
plss help.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you got is Item Level Security

[image]

But this does **not** cover your scenario.

You could achieve your scenario by changing the Ownership of an Item with code. (*I do'nt think a Workflow can change it*)

#### Limit entries

If you are not too tight about security, you could just hide the Edit form for allready entered values:

Starting point: [Limit only one entry per day per user in sharepoint list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/153059/limit-only-one-entry-per-day-per-user-in-sharepoint-list/156829#156829)

Comment: Workflow can actually remove the permissions through impersonation step. Granted that it's better not to do anything than remove permissions with that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an item updating event receiver, and check the value of your field before saving. If the value is set to true, you can just cancel the update event with an error message saying "The fees are already submitted." or something like that.