# Create a list that stops after a certain amount of entrants

Tags: list, web-part, hyperlink, export, image

tl;dr - need to create an image that hyperlinks to an add item form for a list that stops after 15 entrants have been added.

So I have been tasked with creating 4 sign up boards that stop after 15 people have been added to the list.

Originally I used an excel document which used formula to change the hyperlink button after it registered 15 items on the list, I exported the list from SharePoint into Excel and used a pivot table to get the info, I then used an auto-refresh feature in excel so that every time the document was opened it would refresh the table. The issue with this is that (because of licencing) the data connection refresh feature in the excel web part has been disabled. I am stuck at the moment with simply linking the document.

Is there any way to create this using the following criteria without the excel web part data refresh.

- Image/link to the list
- list numbers come up next to this image/link
- image/link changes once it reaches 15 items

If anyone can help then I would greatly appreciate it.

And a bonus if there's some way of deleting all of the items on the list once a month.

Answer (score 0):

#### TL;DR

Search for 'limit entries'

#### Optional reading material

Your Excel method can be applied in SharePoint with a list. Same concept; display List Items and when the maximum is reached do something with you form/button/image.

Details: [Limit only one entry per day per user in sharepoint list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/153059/limit-only-one-entry-per-day-per-user-in-sharepoint-list/156829#156829)