# User should not allow to submit 2 entries on the same week in sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online

i am new to sharepoint online.
i am creating a timesheet in sharepoint list. Please help me with the below requirement.

Solution required:

I have two fields called week start and week end.
User should not allow to submit 2 entries on the same week (Week start and week end).and the production hour should be more than 45 hrs.

Request your help on this. Techies..

[image]

Comment: Please check this [https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/153059/limit-only-one-entry-per-day-per-user-in-sharepoint-list]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limit only one entry per day per user in sharepoint list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/153059/limit-only-one-entry-per-day-per-user-in-sharepoint-list)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, It is still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you will need to use List validation settings to do this. Go list setting>Validation settings, you can enter a formula validate user entries. Like this:
[image]

In this way, users cannot add End date earlier than 14 days plus start date. The screenshot you upload is quite vague so i am not sure the columns you are using. But the option always doable. Production hours will be a bit hard to handle as SharePoint does not recognize working days. Here is an example: [How to calculate number of working hours between 2 dates in a SharePoint Online List?](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1f36f6b4-aafb-4fb4-abbb-8025c9dcc633/how-to-calculate-number-of-working-hours-between-2-dates-in-a-sharepoint-online-list?forum=onlineservicessharepoint)

Other Examples about list formulas here:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/examples-of-common-formulas-in-sharepoint-lists-d81f5f21-2b4e-45ce-b170-bf7ebf6988b3

https://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2015/10/sharepoint-column-validation-examples.html