# Validation Setting to limit registration

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Which setting I can use to prevent a new entry after entry count hits a certain number, say 100?
I tried to use `=IF(COUNTA([Column 1]>100))` then display "Registration Full" in validation setting but it failed.

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

You have to add script to the page disabling the Form when a maximum is reached

`COUNTA` is an Excel formula that doesn't apply to SharePoint

Answered before:

[How to limit the number of entries/records to a maximum in a List](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/150601/how-to-limit-the-number-of-entries-records-to-a-maximum-in-a-list)