# SharePoint Content Approval Check if list item can be edited

Tags: office-365, content-approval

I have content approval enabled in a custom list.  Because of this, if a user userA(with Edit/contribute permission) edits the item and it is pending for approval , another user userB(with Edit/contribute permission) will not be able to edit the same item.  This restriction is enforced only when userB makes all changes in edit form and hits save button.  Is there any way of notifying userB that the selected item cannot be edited on form load itself?

I am looking for a internal column similar to `"Moderation Status"` using which I could determine if the list item can be edited by the current user or not.

Answer (score 0):

I have been asked for a limit on Sharepoint list entry. I used the below code to hide the form. This displas a message and hides the form so that users wont be able to edit the item until certain status is changed.

For getting the status of a column use rest ajax call and add a condition.

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/150727/70872